# Why can't i trigger browser download dialog using zend framework action?

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-headers

I built a tiny script to trigger download dialog as follow:

```
<?php
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.'123.txt');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

ob_end_clean();
echo ' '; 
flush();

//do something long
//for example
sleep(5);
for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){
echo $i . PHP_EOL;
sleep(1);             
}
```

If i place it into a single file called, for example, download.php, It runs correctly; download dialog pops up immediately.

If i place it into a Zend Framework Action with layout and view render disabled, its behaviour is different (download dialog pops up after 15 seconds about).

Why this difference?

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework handles the output of a action and will add extra headers and maybe overwrite headers.

```
 // Disable default phtml rendering
 $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
 $response->clearAllHeaders();
```

For ZF1 we use this line to turn off the normal rendering of the view allowing the download to  work.

Comment: I've already used $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
I tried to add $this->_response->clearAllHeaders(); but nothing changes.